# How do I get gzip or bzip files into a Linux VM on GCP.. I am on a company Windows laptop

Tags: linux, google-cloud-platform, ansible, gzip, rhel8

I am trying to get a gzip file that I downloaded on my Windows laptop locally. The problem is getting the file into a GCP Linux VM/instance. Is there a way to maybe add files to the web and `wget` it into my VM?

So far I've tried Window PowerShell and tried to copy the file into my PuTTY terminal but could not do it.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways:

1. Linux has a secure copy command (`scp`). If you have Google's [Cloud SDK (aka `gcloud`)](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) installed, you can use [`gcloud compute scp`](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/compute/scp) to copy files to/from VMs.
2. If you can access Google's [Cloud Console](https://console.cloud.google.com) for the project, you can use the in-browser SSH tool to [up|down]load files too. Navigate to the Compute Engine VM instances [page](https://console.cloud.google.com/compute/instances) (ensure you select the correct project). Find the VM and then alongside it, click "SSH" under Connect. Once connected, the window includes [up|down]load buttons to transfer files.

[image: SSH-IN-BROWSER]

> **NOTE** Changing a running VM like this may cause problems if there's a need to recreate the VM and there's no changelog for the files uploaded.